# the role of GENERATE_EEK and GET_METADATA in hdfs transparent encryption

Tags: encryption, hdfs, apache-ranger

I am little unclear on what the ACL for GENERATE_EEK and GET_METADATA allow.

From a naive understanding of HDFS transparent encryption it seems that GENERATE_EEK would be a request to generate an EDEK for an encryption zone (EZ).

So say suppose

1. Create a key using the keyadmin user called keyforuserA.
2. Next create a policy for that key , keyforuserA and give userA
   DECRYPT_EEK permissions.
3. Create an encryption zone for userA under /ezforuserA given userA 
   read and writer permissions on that ez. To do this i would need to give GET_METADATA permission on the key keyforuserA to the hdfs superuser either in the policy in step 2. or in a global policy.

Now this userA can read and write any file to the EZ in /ezforuserA

When a userA wants to perform a write in the EZ the namenode requests KMS to generate an EDEK which is then handed off back to userA and since userA can do a DECRYPT_EEK on keyforuserA he is both able to read and write in the EZ.

when does the GENERATE_EEK come into play ? does the hdfs user need this permission for every key ?

similar question for GET_METADATA .. when does this come into play ?